# Statistical significance and findings in APA format?

Tags: statistical-significance, reporting

[image]

I was wondering how to present these findings in APA format? I’m attempting to make my abstract longer by presenting my findings. I’m unsure how to explain the findings properly. I just need one example of one of the columns. The “Equal variance not assumed” does not need to be presented in the findings. The check mark indicates significance.